# URL Parameter in Community

Tags: visualforce

I want to get parameter in community visualforce page.
I tried this code,but i can't get parameter(I got null).
What is  this wrong?

```
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('eid');
```

community url

> https:///servlet/servlet.Integration?lid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&eid=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&ic=1&linkToken=VmpFPSxNakF4T1Mwd015MHdOMVF4TVRveU16bzFNUzR4TWpsYSx3WGViVWlJUGs0VldBU3owR2U2czBnLFlXWmtNR0po

Comment: ``https:///servlet/servlet.Integration`` is not a VF page, but a page to download attachemts

Comment: oh...
but,I tried this community URL「https://<community name>/<page name>/<page name>?targetid={!Account.Id}」,  
I can't get targetId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you give param tag name eid , if you got null then it's mean you're not giving right value of  value- attribute in apex param tag check there(In apex param tag which value you set in value- attribute).
If this helpful for you and your problem will be solve then please tik this question as answered.
Thank You.